# FInding saved fiddles in new Sencha Fiddle

Tags: extjs, sencha-fiddle

I cannot find my saved fiddles in the new Sencha Fiddle :

[image]

I used to be able to click on my name in the top right corner and get a list of saved fiddles.

I can no longer find my saved fiddles.

Comment: Exactly, this happened with me also in morning.

Comment: You have to click on Search Button and then put your username in the author field.

After the search, you will see a list of results containing your fiddles... not so much intuitive... #badUX

Comment: this is terrible UX. Why can't they just provide a link to your own fiddles?

Comment: @OliverWatkins Because Sencha is reknown for making UX worse until the userbase complains: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?331814 https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?332454 https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?331813

Answer (score 3):

Use the search function and enter your own username in the Author field.
[image]